# Google Short URL said 'Dynamic link not found'

Tags: google-chrome

I have been operating a website that uses the goo.gl web shortener for year, but in the past few days, all of the link have been getting the message

> Dynamic Link not found
>
> If you are the developer of this app, ensure that your Dynamic Links
>   domain is correctly configured and that the path component of this URL
>   is valid.

[image]

But I don't even have a firebase account, so why would this be showing up without warning? I am aware that goo.gl will be shutting down soon, but this seems to be specific to my domain (and a few other people who are asking this same question). When I enter in another domain to shorten it works fine.

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to fix this to keep the links working?

P.S It happens when I use the API to create them or if I just create them through the website UI.

Thanks